# Getting references error when importing tone.js

Tags: javascript, express, npm, npm-install, tonejs

I have a basic express.js server setup on my Mac. To this I'm trying to import Tone.js, https://tonejs.github.io, by following the instructions.

```
npm install tone
```

To import Tone.js:

```
import * as Tone from 'tone'
```

But I'm getting this error

*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tone". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

My Package file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "XXXXX",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Run npm start",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon start"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/xxxxx"
  },
  "author": "xxxxx xxxx",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/xxxxxxx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "tone": "^14.7.77"
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe double check if the tone is inside the package.json and run npm install tone again.

Comment: It is, I've tried it all :(

Comment: Are you sure that `tonejs` can run on `nodejs`?

Comment: It's a client side lib so I think so.

Comment: NodeJS is precisely not a client. That should not prevent you from importing it in Node.js and bundle it on a web page though

Comment: https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/ Please check the description. `A Web Audio framework for making interactive music in the browser.` Only for browser

Comment: Currently it's not possible to use tonejs with node: https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/issues/309

Comment: Thank you! A bit unclear on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lars-flieger pointed out, it's not possible to run it one a node.js server.
I ended up downloading Tones.js from here and includes it as a regular script tag.

https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/wiki/Installation